# Advice on implementing a remote worker call logging/database system. Where to start? What is needed?

Tags: database, logging, language-agnostic

This system is to track workers in people's homes across the United Kingdom.

The idea goes something like this:

1. The worker arrives at a customer's home.
2. The worker calls a telephone number and the current time, worker and place are stored on a database.
3. The worker completes his/her task.
4. The worker calls a telephone number and the current time, worker and place is stored again, ending the task.

The idea is to provide an automated time sheet logging system. This is not tied into the payroll but it's just a double check that work is being carried out for the amount of time requested by the customer.

Questions:

1. Where do i start with the phone numbers? Are there services which provide this kind of thing?
2. How to tie the phone record to a database?
3. Have you any experience that may help me?

I've never implemented anything like this before so any help is welcome.

Comment: How do you expect to match the call from worker X with the work for customer Y?

Comment: No idea. Maybe use the customers phone for logging. That will give us the location. Maybe enter a PIN? I'm all for suggestions.

Comment: Using the customer phone is probably a bad idea. He may refuse. Or the number may be unlisted for privacy reasons.

Comment: @p.marino - usually these kinds of things are toll-free so custy shouldn't object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be looking at building this on something like an Interactive Voice Response (IVR) system. From a 50,000 foot view point:

Your worker would call a number and your application would capture something like:

- Worker's ID and PIN  (to authenticate)
- Job ID
- Perhaps extra option to confirm job signon/off

The IVR would then talk to an external application to hand off some pertinent data to your database.

Asterisk supports this sort of thing (as I imagine most telephony server applications would):

> [Asterisk IVR Server](http://www.asterisk.org/applications/ivr)
>   [Asterisk External IVR Interface](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/External+IVR+Interface)

As I said, it's a 50,000 foot finger in the air possible solution.